# Read images from a windows shared folder using opencv in linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opencv, samba

I have a shared folder in another computer (running windows 7) and I can access it using samba shared drive in linux (Ubuntu 14.04)

I want to access the folder data which is an image using opencv and Qt5.

I've read in many articles in internet that Qt is unable to access non local folders and first I need to mount the drive manually.

The problem is that, When I mount the drive in terminal I can't still access the data using Qt and Opencv.

```
cv::Mat Image = cv::imread("smb://mv@10.128.4.41/mvshare/Image.jpg",1); //Image Size is 0*0 !
```

Is there any solution or a reference for that ?

(I've used libsmb, but it is no longer supported and is not working on my laptop !)

Comment: Did you try mounting that smb share somewhere and pointing `cv::imread`to that location?

Comment: @Mohammad How ? Create a link or sth ? please explain more. maybe this is the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Create a directory somewhere, (say `/mnt/share`). Try this `mount -t cifs -o username=mv,password=PASSWD //10.128.4.41/mvshare /mnt/share` at your shell prompt. Then if no error is reported and you can see your files there, `cv::Mat Image = cv::imread("/mnt/share/Image.jpg", 1)` should work too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to configuration your network setting carefully, then using local addressing in cv::imshow() function you can access to content of sheared folder. I have found it :
 http://www.howtogeek.com/176471/how-to-share-files-between-windows-and-linux/
I hope this link help you